# Creating list of repeating qty's of all possible combinations in an array

Tags: microsoft-excel

Looking for some help on a problem. I have an array in Excel with variables in both directions, and the cells corresponding to the QTY at the intersection of each variable combination. Ex input:

[example array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcmsn.png)

|  | Item 1 | Item 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Config 1** | 1 | 2 |
| **Config 2** | 3 | 4 |

I would like to generate an list of each combination of variables, repeated by the QTY for each combination. Ex output:

[ex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgVCf.png)

|  |
| --- |
| Item 1 Config 1 |
| Item 1 Config 2 |
| Item 1 Config 2 |
| Item 1 Config 2 |
| Item 2 Config 1 |
| Item 2 Config 1 |
| Item 2 Config 2 |
| Item 2 Config 2 |
| Item 2 Config 2 |
| Item 2 Config 2 |

I have gotten as far as generating *part* of the first half of the output column (I have a list of "Item 1" repeated 4 times) per [the tutorial on this website](https://excel-bytes.com/how-to-repeat-items-in-a-list-a-various-number-of-times-in-excel/), but I can't figure out how to get the rest of it. Furthermore, all the answers I've found on SU are similarly only concerned with repeating values from a single column -- I am looking to repeat values from an array.

The order does not matter as this will eventually get shuffled later. I have never used VBA or Pivot Tables or Power Query so if this solution requires any of those tools then I will need a lot of hand-holding, but any help would be appreciated regardless. Thank you!

**Bonus Question:**
Supposing the original array had QTY 0 or a letter (i.e. 'X') or perhaps 'N/A' denoting QTY 0:

|  | Item 1 | Item 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Config 1** | 1 | X |
| **Config 2** | 3 | 4 |

I would like to simply exclude it from the list altogether. Intuitively I presume there would be an "if" statement in there somewhere but I'll have to wait and see what the original solution looks like before adding this on to it.

Answer (score 0):

For O365 Beta Channel:

`=LET(ζ,A1:C3,α,DROP(TAKE(ζ,1),,1),β,DROP(TAKE(ζ,,1),1),γ,DROP(ζ,1,1),TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(TRANSPOSE(REPT(α&" "&β&"|",γ))),,"|",1))`

Amend the range referenced (`A1:C3` here) as required, noting that it should include the *Item* row and *Config* column.

Any quantities of zero in the array will be excluded from the returned list.

Alternative for all O365 users:

`=INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&CONCAT(TRANSPOSE(REPT(B1:C1&" "&A2:A3&"</b><b>",B2:C3)))&"</b></a>","//b"),SEQUENCE(SUM(B2:C3)))`